# Button state change

Tags: android, button, ontouchlistener

I'm rather new to android programming and I hit a bump. I want to make a button that changes it's state when pressed, so it will have to states pressed and not pressed. I managed to make the button change state to pressed and keep it like that but I don't know how to make it go back to the not pressed state when clicked again.
here is my code.

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/scaunstg"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/scaunstg"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

the button has an xml file that controls the image displayed.

```
scaunstg.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // show interest in events resulting from ACTION_DOWN
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return true;

        // don't handle event unless its ACTION_UP so "doSomething()" only runs once.
        if(event.getAction()!=MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) return false;
        // doSomething();
        scaunstg.setPressed(true);                   
        return true;
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to add the android tag if you're talking about android :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling setPressed(true) ever time, we need to get the current state of the button and then call setPressed to the opposite. So if the button is pressed, we want to call setPressed(false), and if the button is unpressed then setPressed(true).

We can use the button's isPressed() method for this, and then use the not operator (!) to get the opposite.

```
scaunstg.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        // show interest in events resulting from ACTION_DOWN
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
           return true;

        // don't handle event unless its ACTION_UP so "doSomething()" only runs once.
        if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
           return false;

        // doSomething();
        scaunstg.setPressed( !scaunstg.isPressed() );
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you can do this via XML.To be more exact ,create a xml file in drawable folder (create the folder too, if you don't have it yet)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_sendemail_disable" />
   <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_send_email_click" />
   <item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_sendemail_roll" />
   <item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_sendemail" />
</selector>
```

So, you just give your button a link to this xml file as resource.

Comment: And just for the record ,changing the background of the image from Java is not really resource friendly.It's actually a bad way to approach this thing.